# Unable to send GenericRecord data from Kafka Producer in AVRO format

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

Using confluent-oss-5.0.0-2.11
My **Kafka Producer** code is

```
public class AvroProducer {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("ZOOKEEPER_HOST", "localhost");
        //props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
        props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
        String topic = "confluent-new";

        Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
// I will get below schema string from SCHEMA REGISTRY
        Schema schema = parser.parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"User\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"userName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"uID\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"company\",\"type\":\"string\",\"default\":\"ABC\"},{\"name\":\"age\",\"type\":\"int\",\"default\":0},{\"name\":\"location\",\"type\":\"string\",\"default\":\"Noida\"}]}");

        Producer<String, GenericRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, GenericRecord>(props);
        GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
        record.put("uID", "06080000");
        record.put("userName", "User data10");
        record.put("company", "User data10");
        record.put("age", 12);
        record.put("location", "User data10");

        ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord> recordData = new ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord>(topic, "ip", record);
        producer.send(recordData);

        System.out.println("Message Sent");
    }
```

}

Seems like Producer code is ok and able to see ***Message Sent*** on the console.

**Kafka Consumer** code is:

```
public class AvroConsumer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("ZOOKEEPER_HOST", "localhost");
    props.put("acks", "all");
    props.put("retries", 0);
    props.put("group.id", "consumer1");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
    props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
    String topic = "confluent-new";

    KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
    while(true){
        ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> recs = consumer.poll(10000);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> rec : recs) {
            System.out.printf("{AvroUtilsConsumerUser}: Recieved [key= %s, value= %s]\n", rec.key(), rec.value());
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am unable to see message(data) on the Kafka consumer end. Also I checked the offset count/status for **confluent_new** topic and its not updating. Seems like Producer code is having some problem.
Any pointer would be helpful.

Meanwhile below Producer code is working and here POJO i.e. **User** is avro-tools generated POJO.

```
public class AvroProducer {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
        kafkaParams.put("ZOOKEEPER_HOST", "bihdp01");*/
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("ZOOKEEPER_HOST", "localhost");
        props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
        props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
        String topic = "confluent-new";

        Producer<String, User> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, User>(props);
        User user = new User();
        user.setUID("0908");
        user.setUserName("User data10");
        user.setCompany("HCL");
        user.setAge(20);
        user.setLocation("Noida");
        ProducerRecord<String, User> record = new ProducerRecord<String, User>(topic, (String) user.getUID(), user);
        producer.send(record).get();
        System.out.println("Sent");
    }
```

}

**P.S.** My requirement is to send the received JSON data from source KAFKA topic to destination KAFKA topic in AVRO format. First I am infering AVRO schema from received JSON data using AVRO4S and registering the schema to SCHEMA REGISTRY. Next is to pull data from received JSON and populate in GenericRecord instance and send this GenericRecord instance to Kafka topic using KafkaAvroSerializer. At consumer end I will use KafkaAvroDeserializer to deserialize the received AVRO data.

Comment: `kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");` should be "earliest" instead.

Comment: Producer will buffer locally for a small period. You should `producer.close()` before your app terminates to make sure data is sent.

Comment: Exactly @Hitobat I also figured out the same. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: `ZOOKEEPER_HOST` is not required and isn't a valid Kafka property anyway

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes. I have cleaned the code now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the course of finding solution I tried **Thread.sleep(1000)** and it fixed my problem. Also I tried **producer.send(record).get()** and this also fixed the problem. After going through [Documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html) I came across below code snippet and it hints the solution.

```
// When you're finished producing records, you can 
   flush the producer to ensure it has all been `written` to Kafka and
   // then close the producer to free its resources.

finally {
  producer.flush();
  producer.close();
  }
```

This is the best way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add get() in first Producer

```
producer.send(recordData).get();
```